# How do I specify a class in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change an element from external file (fileA) in fileB. How do I change the background of the specific class (“card-body” whose child class has “input_container”, or text of “…”) WITHOUT adding another id to specify, since “card-body” is used in other parts of the file? (The reason why I cannot add an id to specify is that the fileA is inside fixtures file)

Thank you so much in advance!

fileA:

```
<div class="card-body py-3">
      <div class="input_container” data-label="incentive">…</div>
      <div id="incen_text" class="py-3 input_container”>;;;</div>  
</div>
```

FileB:

```
 <label for="Color">Choose your color</label>
 <input type="color" id="Color" value="#ff0000">….
 <script>
$(function(){
$("#Color").on("change", function(){
  $(‘.card-body’).each(function(){
      if($(this).children().hasClass(‘.input_container’)) {
        $(this).css(“background-color”, $(‘#Color’).val())
      };
   });
  });
});
```

I also tried this:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
    $("#Color").on("change", function(){
    $(‘.card-body’).each(function(){
       x=$(".input_container").text();
      if(x == “…”){
                 $(this).css(“background-color”, $(‘#Color’).val())
         }
      });
  });
  });

</script>
```

Comment: The quotes are wrong in a few places. I assume it's a copy paste issue from another program? Is this how the code appears in your script? If so then it's not going to work.

Comment: There's a bunch of ways to target a specific element. Here you could use `$('.input_container).closest('.card-body')`.

Comment: Are both FileA and FileB visible at the same time? Or is it 2 difference html pages?

Comment: It's specifically about the quotes. You have `“` and `”` but it's supposed to be `"`. Same for the single quotes. This typically happens when you write code in an app intended to be used for "human text".

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you for your reply. I tried this, but I get the same result when I do it like `$('.card-body').css`

Comment: Always check your browser console (F12) for errors - if the code you've provided *is* the code you've tried, then you'll be seeing `113 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` due to the dodgy quotes

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Thank you for answering. It is 2 different html pages.

Comment: Add `console.log(x)` - see what you're *actually* getting.

Comment: @freedomn-m, I have fixed the code and now I dont have the error, but still I cannot apply the change to a specific class.

Comment: *after fixing all the bad quotes* - `$(".input_container").text()` will get *all* the texts for *all* the divs with`.input_container` - as you have two, it combines them into "... ;;;" which !== "..."

Comment: From what I can guess you're trying to do, you could do: `$(".input_container").filter((i,e) => $(e).text() == "xxx").closest(".card-body").css("background-color", "red");`  https://jsfiddle.net/27psvcqe/  but if they're on different pages, then I don't see how you're trying to affect them as they're not on the same page (at least not with just js)

Comment: I have data label in the ".input_container", is there any way I can specify the ".card-body" using this data label?

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your question to include what you mean by "data label".   Given that you have multiple `.card-body` you can't specify ".card-body" as that will be all of them and you'll need to use relative DOM navigation and/or `this` (inside an event handler or `each`).     By "specific class", do you mean "a specific instance of a class"?  Because `$(".card-body").css("color", "red")` clearly works fine.

Comment: @hika Unless both pages are loaded and present at the same time, then you can't, make it work with the code you have. You have to look into localStorage

Comment: Put simply, when you open a URL, the browser loads the HTML, then runs the scripts in order, both the inline ones and referenced ones. When a script changes something, the effect is immediate and will disappear when a new page is loaded or the current page is refreshed. So there's no simple way to "change file B from file A" if both are HTML files loaded at different times. By now I'm 99% confident this is a massive [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Your code looks like the user can select a color, so if this is about implementing a color theme, you need to store the color first anyway.